# Windows Store App - Dynamic Binding

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Need a second set of eyes. I am dynamically populating a hub control with text boxes, check boxes, etc... As I do this I am adding databinding to each control as I add it.  The problem is that any changes made after the load event are not registering properly. Basically not registering at all. My object implements iNotifyPropertyChanged. Here are some snippets to hopefully better explain the scenario.

**Dynamic control creation and databinding**

```
  var b = new Binding
            {
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                Source = detail.Answer
            };

            var txtBx = new TextBox() { Width = 260, Height = 18, Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 5) };
            txtBx.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, b);
```

**Object Property**

```
   public string Answer
    {
        get
        {
            return _answer;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == _answer) return;
            _answer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Answer));

        }
    }
```

**Property change method**

```
 [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

What am I missing?  Appreciate the feedback as always

Comment: Is this thing on? lol. Am I asking something that isnt common perhaps?  It may be better to consider a different approach to my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the binding path and I used always the static SetBinding:

```
var binding = new Binding
        {
            Source = _sectionHeaderSlider,
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
            Path = new PropertyPath("Value"),
        };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(ScrollTransform, Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.CompositeTransform.TranslateXProperty, binding);
```